# Keep default value in textbox on focus

Tags: javascript, html

I created an input field (text) on a website with the default value "DE". Now i'm having the following problem.

```
<input type="text" id="iban" value="DE" />
```

When the user clicks in the textbox the default value "DE" should **not** be deleted and the user should only add numbers after the default value in the textbox. So i'm searching for a js function which makes the default value of a textbox as readonly. The user should not delete the default value.

If this is possible, how does it work?

Comment: I don't want that the value will be deleted on focus. I'm searching for a function where i can mark a part of a textbox as read only. And yes i searched for it, but I didn't found a solution for this.

Comment: Thx, i will try this Danny Beckett.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use JavaScript. Simple HTML and CSS will do the job just fine.

Move `DE` into a `<span>` to the left of your `<input>`:

```
<span class="iban">DE</span><input type="text" id="iban" />
```

Then position the `<span>` *inside* the `<input>`:

```
span.iban
{
    position: relative;
}

input#iban
{
    margin-left: -25px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
```

The above code produces:

[image]

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NUqsn/).

Comment: @Downvoter Please explain...

Comment: The user needs to enter only numbers, it isn't?

Comment: @Arkana The main question here is how to keep a default value in a textbox. That is why *your* answer has received 2 downvotes.

Comment: @Arkana The OP has now accepted this answer. Please remove your downvote.

Comment: Thats what i want. Thank you. The point with the numbers was not the main point of my question. I know how that works ;)

Comment: That's the OP opinion, not mine ;) If I need to do something like this and find this question, your answer will doesn't fit to me. Calm down. At last, we're here to *help users*, do not take it as a competition, man.

Answer (score 5):

You can't make a part of the value as read-only... But if you want to use a simple solution (without javascript) you could use two inputs :

```
<input type="text" id="iban-prefix" value="DE" readonly/><input type="text" id="iban-value"/>
```

Arrange them using css and just concat the two values in your sever side.

OR :

A javascript solution : on your form use the "onsubmit" event to call a javascript function to check if the "DE" prefix is present in the value entered by the user and if not, add the "DE" prefix.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score -2):

You can try this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#iban").keydown(function(event) {

            if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57 || event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8) {
                event.preventDefault(); 
            }   

    });
});
```

I found it here: https://snipt.net/GerryEng/jquery-making-textfield-only-accept-numeric-values/

EDIT: And modify it to **prevent backspace and delete keys**.

[A working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbsCy/2/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: It's Not working in Firefox browser

Comment: Sorry, as Danny said, thats not what i searched for

Comment: Just to let you know, deleting this answer will increase your reputation, since it has a negative score.